# AutoGPT .env.template file

Tags: git, docker-compose, failed-installation, .env, autogpt

need help with .env file, When I first started I had a .env.template file, renamed it, just like the instructions said. Didn't work, I restarted completely. but Now when i download/copy I don't have a .env.template  file only .env file and it show as notepad symbol on the directory and when i try to run "docker compose build auto-gptat" i get "Failed to load C:\Users\infoa\Desktop\Auto-GPT\AutoGPT NEW\AutoGPT.env: open C:\Users\infoa\Desktop\Auto-GPT\AutoGPT NEW\AutoGPT.env: The system cannot find the file specified."